# Prevent handlers assigned on document ready from being removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm generating and appending several spans to divs on page load.

HTML structure like:

```
    <div id="holder">
        <div id="grid"></div>
    </div>
```

Then loop through and append spans to the nested div:

```
    $span = $('<span />').attr('class', 'colorSquare');
    $("#grid").append($span);
```

Then, I want to click a button and reset (delete the originally appended spans, because I don't want to reappend spans) what's inside the div's with:

```
    $("#holder > div").html("");
```

On initial page load / initial generation of spans inside the div, the `click` event handler is registered to the div's spans on `document.ready` , and the following works:

```
$("#grid span").click(function () { console.log("working"); });
```

However, after resetting with `$("#holder > div").html("");`, the click handler doesn't work. I'm assuming this is because the handler is only assigned on initial document ready, but I wasn't expecting all handlers to be removed once you reset the div's content. How do I prevent assigned handlers from being removed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are assigning the click handler onto the `span` element that you have added to `#grid`.  When you clear `#grid`, you also remove the `span` and therefore you lose the click handler.  You will either have to re-assign the handler again as soon as another `span` is created, or use an alternate handler that is tied to an element that does not get removed (such as `#grid`):

```
$('#grid').on('click', 'span', function() { console.log("working"); });
```

This alternative uses jQuery's `on` method, and binds the handler to the `#grid` element.  However, the second parameter labels that you only care about clicking on `span` elements which are children of `#grid`.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for also describing the problem.